# iPhone - Changing a sub-sub-sub NSMutableDictionary value

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, key-value

If I have a data tree that is something like :

```
NSMutableDictionary (dict1)
   NSMutableDictionary (dict2)
      NSMutableArray (array)
        NSMutableDictionary (dict3)
           Key1
           Key2

        NSMutableDictionary (dict_n)
           Keyn
           Keyn

   NSMutableDictionary (dict_n)
      NSMutableArray (array_n)
        NSMutableDictionary (dict_n)
           Keyn
           Keyn

        NSMutableDictionary (dict_n)
           Keyn
           Keyn
```

If I want to change the value of Key1, is there a simplier way than...

getting dict1
then getting dict2
then getting array
then getting dict3

converting dict3 to a mutable Dictionary
then setting key1

Converting array to a mutable array
then setting dict3 into array

converting dict2 to a mutable Dictionary
then setting array into dict2

converting dict1 to a mutable Dictionary
then setting dict2 into dict1

Doing that for each value I have to change is a real headache, and really code consuming.

Comment: Why are you doing the three last steps? Also, do you want to set Key1 to a certain value in all dictionaries in the array or only one dictionary?

Comment: @Bavarious makes an excellent point: if you're just changing the value for a key in an existing dict3, you don't need to do anything to dict1, dict2, or the array.

Comment: @Bavarious : That's wrong. When getting an object from a Dictionary, it  returns a non mutable object. So you can't set a value inside it. To do so, you must convert it into a NEW Mutable object, set the value you want to change, then insert it back into its parent to make the change available. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Oliver: It's _your_ data structure -- if it's inconvenient, use something else. If you're creating the structure yourself, use mutable containers rather than immutable ones. If you're reading it from a file, use -propertyListWithData:options:format:error: and specify an appropriate mutability option. And no matter what, put the code that deals directly with the data in a model controller as described in my post below.

Comment: @Caleb : Yes, but that's not the point. In that kind of structure, I was pointing the fact that you need that kind of cascade calls, and cannot just set the child attribute. It's just not settable as is, even if set as mutable (objectAtIndex seems to return non mutable objects. You answer bellow is the one I'm testing now.

Comment: @Oliver, my point is that you shouldn't use immutable data structures if you'll need to modify the data. All the containers (set, array, dictionary, data) have mutable and immutable versions, and it's up to you to choose the appropriate variety. Immutability is often a big benefit. `-objectAtIndex:` returns mutable objects if that's what you stored in the array.

Comment: @Caleb : Well.... I don't use non mutable structures. For example, I've stored a mutableArray and objectAtIndex returned me a non mutable one. Same thing with the NSMutableDictonary... I'll make some more tries. Did you try what you say ?  Note : I store the whole thing in NSUserDefaults, perhaps it's the cause of the non mutable returns of sub-sub objects ?

Comment: @Caleb : I made the tests : objectForkey returns non mutable objects. Test this : `NSUserDefaults* def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray* mutarr = [NSMutableArray array];
    [mutarr addObject:@"test"];
    
    [def setObject:mutarr forKey:@"thekey"];
    
    NSMutableArray* restoredarr = [def objectForKey:@"thekey"];
    [restoredarr addObject:@"test2"];
    
    [def setObject:restoredarr forKey:@"thekey"];`     It crashes the app with "[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object"

Comment: @Oliver, you're right that NSUserDefaults is the reason you're getting back immutable containers. Objects stored in the defaults system will (obviously) be written out to a file and then reconstituted later -- they're not the same objects at that point. Consider storing your data in your own file rather than (ab)using the defaults system, and use the method I cited above to get mutable containers when you read the file. It's often said that if something that seems simple is very difficult in Cocoa, you're probably doing it wrong. I think that applies here.

Comment: Oh, I’ve missed the discussion. The problem is that `NSUserDefaults` always returns immutable objects as Caleb stated; otherwise, you could save some code by using mutable objects. For cases like this, I prefer to use a domain-aware `Preferences` class of my own that internally reads from and writes to `NSUserDefaults` but exposes a cleaner interface, much like Caleb’s answer.

Comment: @Bavarious : That's the option I've retained :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send a message to an object unless you have a pointer to that object, so in a basic sense the answer to your question is no, there's no other way.

However, one presumes that this data structure that you have represents some sort of data model. As such, it should probably be contained in some sort of model class that understands its parts, and that class should be the only one that needs to understand how the data is stored. The model class should offer a higher-level interface to the data. Say dict3 represents one particular vehicle in a fleet, and the keys are things like "vehicleTag", "registrationDate", "purchaseDate", etc. Maybe the dictionaries at the dict2 level the fleets in different regions, and dict2 itself represents the northeast fleet. Then the VehiclePool class, your model class which stores all the data, might offer methods like:

```
-registrationDateForVehicle:(int)vehicleIndex inFleet:(NSString*)fleetKey;
-setRegistrationDate:(NSDate*)regDate forVehicle:(int)vehicleIndex inFleet:(NSString*)fleetKey;
```

I'm not sure I'd really want an API like that -- I'd prefer to get the list of vehicles for a given fleet and then operate on those with simpler accessors, but you seem to want to avoid several levels of accessors. The point here is that you shouldn't be writing a ton of code to do the operations you need; you should write methods that know how to access the data and then call those.

Answer (score 2):

The [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation states:

> In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when using key-value coding the key must be a string (see “Key-Value Coding Fundamentals”).

Therefore, if your keys (and sub-keys) are all strings, you can do the following to retrieve and set values:

```
id myNestedObject = [topLevel valueForKeyPath:@"firstKey.secondKey.thirdKey"];
[topLevel setObject:newNestedObject forKeyPath:@"firstKey.secondKey.thirdKey"];
```

Comment: It’s not as simple as that because of the array.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't noticed the array. Perhaps @Oliver could change the NSArray to a dictionary with keys "0", "1", "2", ... ;-)